# Using current_date to get beginning and end of month for the past 12 months

Tags: postgresql, performance, date, group-by, summary

I am writing the following query to calculate the sales rate by month, and I want to make sure it always looks at the interval: 1st to end of month, for the past 12 months. I have tried the following, but I am not sure it takes the 1st and last of the month and I feel it can be written in a shorter query?

```
select 
datetrunc('month',date)
,count(id) filter (where status='sold' and (date between (datetrunc('month','current_date - interval '1 months')) and datetrunc('month', current_date) - Interval '1 days'))
/ count(id) filter (where date between (datetrunc('month','current_date - interval '1 months')) and datetrunc('month', current_date) - Interval '1 days') as Mar2020_Sales_Rate
,..... as Feb2020_Sales_Rate
,.
,.
,..... as Mar2019_Sales_Rate
from sales
group by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I chose to get 1st and end of the month, without using current date, but rather the creation date (of an order) in my data. Please suggest any other query that might seem more effective or if you feel there is a flaw in this query:

```
select distinct creation_date::date,
       (creation_date - Interval '1 months')::date as Minus_1M,
       (creation_date - Interval '2 months')::date as Minus_2M,
       (creation_date - Interval '3 months')::date as Minus_3M,
       ...
       (creation_date - Interval '12 months')::date as Minus_12M,
       extract('day' from creation_date) as Day_of_month,
       date_trunc('month', (creation_date::date - extract('day' from 
       creation_date)::int))::date as Beginning_of_month,
       creation_date::date - extract('day' from creation_date)::int as End_of_month
from order_data
order by 1 desc;
```